# What does the CI interval mean?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, t-test

I created a plot with the help of [ggbetweenstats](https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/articles/web_only/ggbetweenstats.html):

[image: img]

I wonder about the meaning of the CI-interval which is [-0.37, 1.49]. What does this mean?
Sorry for cutting the labels on the y-axis. The numbers there go from around 60 to 80.

Comment: in theory, yes, but how do those values apply to the data above? This is what I wonder. Probably I lack some general understanding about CI. Or in other words: I understood such that the confidence interval represents the "interval" in which the expectation value/mean lies with a probability of e.g. 95 %. So, I would expect an interval of about like [63, 68] ?

Comment: it should be a confidence interval for a difference in means (first group - second group). However the numbers do not match between the figure and the text. You need to figure out what the "g_Hedges" is and the given confidence interval will most likely be for the same quantity. It's probably a mean difference expressed as effect size.